# How to debug node.js backend written in es6/es7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to debug es7 source code directly. I found the only one working way to debug already transpired es5 code, but it is very inconvenient. I tried `babel-node --inspect my_es7_file.js`, but it doesn't work. Also `babel-node-debug` doesn't work too. There is my code example which I want to debug:

```
import path from 'path';

const run = async filename => {
    console.log('filename', filename);

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

    debugger;

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

    const newPath = path.resolve(__dirname, filename);

    console.log('newPath', newPath);

    return newPath;
}

run('hello.js').then(process.exit);
```

this code works well when I run it using babel-node

UPD I don't like Webstorm and VS Code. I want to write code in Atom and debug it in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you need to have Babel produce source maps (the `--source-maps` flag). So for instance, if you have `babel-cli` installed locally:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

And you set up a build script in your `package.json`, perhaps taking all scripts in `src` and compiling them to `dest`:

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dest --source-maps"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "blah",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "~6.24.1"
  }
}
```

Then if you have, say, `src/test.js`, you'd build it with `npm run build`:

```
npm run build
```

...and then you can debug it via

```
node --inspect --debug-brk dest/test.js
```

(That's assuming Node v6.3.0 or higher, which has inspector built in. Prior, you'd need to use `node-inspector` or similar.)

That will give you a URL to paste into Chrome to fire up the debugger, and will stop on the first line (that's the `--debug-brk` part) so you don't have to hav `debugger;` in your code.

Again: The key bit is `--source-maps`, integrate it into your build script (gulp, grunt, npm itself, whatever) however you want.

---

Re your comment:

> it doesn't work with es6 even with source-maps

Yes, it does:

`src/test-es6.js`:

```
const x = n => n * 2;
console.log(x(2)); // 4
```

Using the `package.json` above, and this `.babelrc` (since by "with ES6" I take it you want to transpile ES2015+ to ES5):

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Build:

```
$ npm run build

> btemp@0.0.0 build /home/example
> babel src -d dest --source-maps

src/test-es6.js -> dest/test-es6.js
```

Contents of the resulting `dest/test-es6.js`:

```
"use strict";

var x = function x(n) {
  return n * 2;
};
console.log(x(2)); // 4
```

Running:

```
$ node --inspect --debug-brk dest/test-es6.js
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/8dd843bf-16d5-477f-bacf-f72e2dfd6bbc
```

Going to that URL:[image]

This is using Node v7.7.2, but anything from v6.3.0 and up should work.

It would appear that sometimes, it doesn't automatically open the `src` file for you (it did for me when I ran the above; I just tried again, several times, and it didnt'). When it doesn't, you may see this:

[image: running es6-2]

Note the "Source Map detected" notice. If so, just expand the file tree on the left, navigate to `src`, and pick the file. You can then debug the ES2015 source. I don't know why it sometimes fails to open the file for you automatically.

Comment: it doesn't work with es6 even with source-maps. I found the workaround: use node 6.3.1 and babel-node-debug

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko: It does. You may need to change your presets and/or other options, but it does work. Mind you, if you're sticking to "ES6" (that is, ES2015), with Node v6.3.0 you don't need Babel at all other than for module support.

Comment: No, it doesn't. In devtools it writes "Source map detected", but in the file tree, there are no .map files. There are only transpiled files. With version 7.10.0 it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko: Yes, it works. See update in the answer. You just need a `.babelrc` option to tell it to transpile ES2015 to ES5.

Comment: I'd already got .babelrc with preset "latest". Switched to node 7.7.2, made all steps you have written and saw an empty devtools.

Comment: also if I use node 6.3.1 with your approach it at least shows me the transpiled code.

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko: I just went through the steps again, and it would appear sometimes it doesn't automatically open the file from `src` for you. But the mapping *does* work, see above starting just under the first screenshot, with *"It would appear that sometimes, it doesn't automatically open the src file for you..."*

Comment: @DmitryNalyvaiko : Are you using Chrome or Chromium ?
I had the same problem as you with Chromium, then I tried with Chrome and everything was working as tjcrower said.
Chrome & Chromium are Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: My node version is v7.10.0.

Comment: @GeraudGratacap I use Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do that using node 6.3.1 version and babel-node-debug. Before it, I used node 7.10.0 version. Also, there is no need to add `debugger;` into the source code. There is ability to add breakpoints directly in chrome dev tools, after running `babel-node-debug my_es6_script.js`

I guess this is the only solution for this moment.

Again to debug es6/es7 node.js code, you need to use node 6.3.1 and babel-node-debug.

Comment: *"I guess this is the only solution for this moment."* No, it isn't. As I detail, in detail, in my answer.